# How to enable sockets in php as mentioned in the manual?

Tags: php, sockets

I have Xampp installed and want to work with sockets in php, so I started with the sample code from http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php on localhost.
I got this well known error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\simpletcpipserver.php on line 14

After searching the web I changed the PHP.ini files:
I removed the `;` from `extension=php_sockets.dll` and edited this part to:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = C:\xampp\php\ext
```

php_sockets.dll is present at that location.

But still I get the same error.

I did see this on http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.installation.php:
`The socket functions described here are part of an extension to PHP which must be enabled at compile time by giving the --enable-sockets option to configure.`

Apart from what I already did, I don't understand what this means.

Would should I do now to get the sample code to work?

Comment: Did you restart Apache after changing php.ini?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I still get the same error. Rebooting and reinstalling xampp didn't change anything either.

Comment: What version of PHP came with XAMPP? I just tried the sample with 7.2.6 and it worked correctly. If you do a `phpinfo()` on your installation do you see a section for Sockets Support (likely between SimpleXML and SPL)?